# How can I select the second cancel button instead of the first?

Tags: javascript, ruby, watir, firewatir

I want to cancel the second line item instead of the first.

Below is some sample code for the 2 line items:

```
<div class="screenlet-body">
        <form name="updateItemInfo" method="post" action="/ordermgr/control/updateOrderItems">
        <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="140070"/>

        <input type="hidden" name="orderItemSeqId" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="shipGroupSeqId" value=""/>
          <input type="hidden" name="supplierPartyId" value="10964"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="orderTypeId" value="PURCHASE_ORDER"/>
        <table class="basic-table order-items" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="header-row">
                <td width="25%">Product</td>
                <td width="10">Part Condition</td>

                <td width="25%">Status</td>
                <td width="5%" class="align-text">Quantity</td>
                <td width="10%" class="align-text">Unit Price</td>

                <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="10%" class="align-text">Sub Total</td>
                <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>

                <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
                                       <tr><td colspan="8"><hr/></td></tr>
                  <tr>
                          <td valign="top">
                                <div>
                                   10588 - 
                                    NAS516-1A 
                                       - ZERk FITTING 
                          </td>

                          <td>

                              <select name="icon_00001">
                                  <option/>
                                  <option value="ARM">As Removed</option>
                                  <option value="INP">Inspected&#47; Tested</option>
                                  <option value="NES">New Surplus</option>
                                  <option value="NEW">New</option>

                                  <option value="OVH">Overhauled&#47; Remanufactured</option>
                                  <option value="RPR">Repaired&#47; Serviceable</option>
                                  <option value="UNK">Unknown</option>
                              </select>
                          </td>

                          <td>
                              Current&nbsp;Created<br/>
                              2011-03-11 09&#58;16&#58;57.0&nbsp;Created<br/>
                          </td>
                          <td class="align-text" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">

                              Ordered&nbsp;5&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>
                              Cancelled:&nbsp;0&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>
                              Remaining:&nbsp;5&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>
                          </td>
                          <td class="align-text" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                                  <input type="text" size="8" name="ipm_00001" value="10"/>

                                  &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="opm_00001" value="Y"/>
                          </td>
                          <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          <td class="align-text" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
```

$50.00

```
                      <tr><td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                          <tr>
                              <td align="right"><span class="label">Ship Group</span></td>
                              <td align="left"> &nbsp;[00001] 2920 E. Chambers St.</td>
                              <td align="right"><span class="label">Quantity</span></td>
                              <td align="right">
                                  <input type="text" name="iqm_00001:00001" size="6" value="5"/> 
                                      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItem" value="00001">

                              </td>
                              <td>
                                      &nbsp;
                              </td>
                              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td align="right">
                                      <a id="cancel_00001" name="cancel_00001 "href="javascript:document.updateItemInfo.action='/ordermgr/control/cancelOrderItem';document.updateItemInfo.orderItemSeqId.value='00001';document.updateItemInfo.shipGroupSeqId.value='00001';document.updateItemInfo.submit()" class="buttontext">Cancel</a>
                              </td>

                          </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td align="right">
                        <span class="label">Comments</span>
                      </td>
                      <td colspan="7" align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="icm_00001" value="" size="30" maxlength="60"/>

                    </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                          <span class="label">Delivery Date</span>
                      </td>
                      <td colspan="7" align="left" colspan="7">
                          <input type="text" name="iddm_00001" value="2011-03-31 12:49:16.000" size="25" maxlength="30"/>
                          <a href="javascript:call_cal(document.updateItemInfo.iddm_00001,'2011-03-11 00:00:00.0');"><img src="/images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Click here For Calendar"/></a>

                      </td>
                    </tr>
```

---

```
                                <div>
                                   10602 - 
                                    MS21075L3N 
                                       - NUTPLATE 
                          </td>

                          <td>
                              <select name="icon_00002">
                                  <option/>
                                  <option value="ARM">As Removed</option>
                                  <option value="INP">Inspected&#47; Tested</option>

                                  <option value="NES">New Surplus</option>
                                  <option value="NEW" selected>New</option>
                                  <option value="OVH">Overhauled&#47; Remanufactured</option>
                                  <option value="RPR">Repaired&#47; Serviceable</option>
                                  <option value="UNK">Unknown</option>

                              </select>
                          </td>

                          <td>
                              Current&nbsp;Created<br/>
                          </td>
                          <td class="align-text" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                              Ordered&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>

                              Cancelled:&nbsp;0&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>
                              Remaining:&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>
                          </td>
                          <td class="align-text" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                                  <input type="text" size="8" name="ipm_00002" value="100"/>
                                  &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="opm_00002" value="Y"/>
                          </td>

                          <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          <td class="align-text" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
```

$100.00

```
                      <tr><td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td align="right"><span class="label">Ship Group</span></td>

                              <td align="left"> &nbsp;[00001] 2920 E. Chambers St.</td>
                              <td align="right"><span class="label">Quantity</span></td>
                              <td align="right">
                                  <input type="text" name="iqm_00002:00001" size="6" value="1"/> 
                                      <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItem" value="00002">
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                      &nbsp;

                              </td>
                              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td align="right">
                                      <a id="cancel_00002" name="cancel_00002 "href="javascript:document.updateItemInfo.action='/ordermgr/control/cancelOrderItem';document.updateItemInfo.orderItemSeqId.value='00002';document.updateItemInfo.shipGroupSeqId.value='00001';document.updateItemInfo.submit()" class="buttontext">Cancel</a>
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td align="right">

                        <span class="label">Comments</span>
                      </td>
                      <td colspan="7" align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="icm_00002" value="This is a comment." size="30" maxlength="60"/>

                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">

                          <span class="label">Delivery Date</span>
                      </td>
                      <td colspan="7" align="left" colspan="7">
                          <input type="text" name="iddm_00002" value="" size="25" maxlength="30"/>
                          <a href="javascript:call_cal(document.updateItemInfo.iddm_00002,'2011-03-11 00:00:00.0');"><img src="/images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Click here For Calendar"/></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
```

```
<td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Update Items" class="buttontext"/> </td>
```

What I need to do is cancel the second line item on the order.
There is 4 large windows showing code.
The second large one is the first line item and the fourth large one is the second line item.
I need to cancel the second.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I be the first to say: ???. This question makes no sense, and is not really a question at all.

Comment: I agree. Curtis, you might put the html sample in here (use the code feature), make sure it includes all relevant frames and cancel  buttons, and what code you have tried so far.

Comment: if you think the question is not a good one, feel free do downvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured out a way to do it using this line of code:

```
browser.link(:url, "javascript:document.updateItemInfo.action='/ordermgr/control/cancelOrderItem';document.updateItemInfo.orderItemSeqId.value='00002';document.updateItemInfo.shipGroupSeqId.value='00001';document.updateItemInfo.submit()").click
```

The way it works is I specify the first value to reflect the line item number which will cancel out the specified line item.

Thanks for your help guys.